# how to grap data from a local website with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, get

I need a hint how to grap data from a website. I am quite new to web grapping. The special thing is that I have no access to the website because it runs locally on another network. For development I only have the website as an html file. Know my problem is that I get an error with my following code. I think the problem is quite simple but I do not have an idea so far.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'file:///tmp/mozilla/LiveData.html' # file is locally so far
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

I get the following error:

```
NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc151db7550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Maybe it does not work when it is local and not a "real" website. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can not use `.get` on local file. Instead read the file using `open`

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `.get` method on local file. Read the file first and then pass it to `bs4.`
You can achieve similar thing with something like this.
Example:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url = 'file:///tmp/mozilla/LiveData.html' # file is locally so far
with open('/tmp/mozilla/LiveData.html', 'r') as f:
    response = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get` is returning the response from the website after sending a get request to the URL. Since your website is just a local file, rather than running live (and listening for requests), it's not returning anything from the get request.

> requests.get(url, params=None, **kwargs)[source] Sends a GET request.
>
> Parameters:    url – URL for the new Request object. params – (optional)
>   Dictionary, list of tuples or bytes to send in the query string for
>   the Request.
>   **kwargs – Optional arguments that request takes. Returns:     Response object
>
> Return type:   requests.Response

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, one additional question for understanding, in case the website is running live, then I only have to replace Poojan solution with the .get command, right?

Comment: Your website would need to also be listening for incoming requests in order to provide a response. I'm assuming you'd have some flask server that will listen for get requests, then return the appropriate response. Here's a useful flask tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/flask-get-post-requests-handling-tutorial/